# Problems changing the date with a trigger in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date, triggers

I want to create a trigger that can modify or insert a date in my table "contracts":

"If a client with a current contract signs a new one, the end date
Of the previous one will be a day before the start date of the new one"

So, my **trigger** is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER_D
BEFORE
INSERT OR UPDATE ON CONTRACTS
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
idcliente CONTRACTS.CLIENTID%TYPE;
fecha_fin CONTRACTS.ENDDATE%TYPE;
BEGIN
  if :NEW.CLIENTID = idcliente  
    then 
    if TO_CHAR(fecha_fin) IS NULL OR TO_CHAR(fecha_fin) > TO_CHAR(:NEW.STARTDATE)
      then
        INSERT INTO CONTRACTS (ENDDATE) VALUES 
        (:NEW.STARTDATE);
        update CONTRACTS
        set
          ENDDATE = :NEW.STARTDATE;
    end if;      
  end if;
END;
```

I tried to insert a row like this:

```
INSERT INTO CONTRACTS (CONTRACTID, CLIENTID, STARTDATE, ENDDATE, CONTRACT_TYPE ,ADDRESS ,TOWN, ZIPCODE, COUNTRY)
VALUES              ('TW42260/09','99/98480296/22T',TO_DATE('18/04/17','DD/MM/YY'), NULL ,'Flat Rate Lover','69 Citadel Street, Ground floor, door 1','Summer forest', '11164' ,'Taiwan, Province of China');
```

This trigger compiles well, but they are not doing anything on the table.

Comment: You aren't setting `idcliente` so the first comparison will never be true (same for `fecha_fin`), so the trigger does nothing. If you insert/update inside the trigger it will fire again,so you're risking recursion, and the update will get a mutating table error. Does your assignment require you to use a trigger?

Comment: Why do you compare STRINGS by "bigger than"?

Comment: It was a work fot the university

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER_D
BEFORE
INSERT OR UPDATE ON CONTRACTS
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
  UPDATE CONTRACTS
  SET    ENDDATE   = :NEW.STARTDATE - INTERVAL '1' DAY
  WHERE  CLIENTID  = :NEW.CLIENTID
  AND    ENDDATE   > :NEW.STARTDATE
  AND    STARTDATE < :NEW.STARTDATE;
END;
```

However, it is updating the table that the trigger is monitoring and it seems likely that the trigger will cause updates that will invoke the trigger again and get a mutating table error.

You might be better to wrap your business logic in a stored procedure where it can perform the update on the previous rows and then do the insert/update. Then, rather than performing DML statements directly on the table instead invoke the stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks you very much, I just put "insert" on the trigger and the mutant table disapear, because I didn't really use the "update" option. Thank you so much :)